# how do I pass the selected parameters in the checkbox from one jsp page to another jsp page?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox

I have to make the switch to selected values ​​within some checkboxes in a jsp page but after the selection and after pressing the "Send" button, I generate this error with the following description: HTTP Status 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Where am I wrong?

**TaskController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newTask", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String task(@ModelAttribute Task task, Model model) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String s = auth.getName();
        Student student = studentFacade.retrieveUser(s);
        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        if(!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            jobs = facadeJob.retriveAlljobs();
            model.addAttribute("job", getMathRandomList(jobs));
            model.addAttribute("image", imageFacade.retriveAllImages());
            List<Image> img = imageFacade.retriveAllImages();
            task.setImages(img);
            task.setStudent(student);
            taskFacade.addTask(task);
            List<Long> images = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Image i : img)
                images.add(i.getId());
            model.addAttribute("images", images);


        }
        return "users/newTask";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/taskRecap", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String taskRecap(@ModelAttribute Task task, Model model,BindingResult result) {
        model.addAttribute("task", task);
        return "users/taskRecap";
    }
```

**newTask.jsp**

```
<form:form method="post" action="taskRecap" modelAttribute="task" name="form">
    <form:checkboxes path="images" items="${images}"  value="yes" />
        <td><input type="submit" value="Send" /></td>
 </form:form>
```

**`taskRecap.jsp`**

### Immages

```
<c:forEach var="image" items="${task.images}">
        <c:out value="${image.id}" />
        </c:forEach>
```

**Task.java**

```
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
    @ManyToMany
    List<Image> images;


    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Task() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Task(Long id, Student student, List<Image> images) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.student = student;
        this.images = images;
    }

    public List<Image> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I would say the best way to send it is through hidden variable or through query param

Answer (score 2):

Using Query parameter

```
<a href="edit.jsp?Name=${user.name}" />
```

Using Hidden variable .

```
<form method="post" action="update.jsp">  

   <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="${user.id}">
```

if you use either of the first 2 methods you can access your value like this:

```
String userid = session.getParameter("Name");
```

you can send Using Session object.

```
session.setAttribute("Name", UserName);
```

These values will now be available from any jsp as long as your session is still active.

if you use the third option you can access your value like this:

```
 String userid = session.getAttribute("Name");
```

Comment: "session.getParameter("Name");" maybe you want to say "request.getParameter("Name");" ?

Comment: @0bj3ct No i want to say what ever i have written, there is three scope Page, REquest and Session

Comment: and Application scope

Comment: @0bj3ct Yes Application / Context scope also